# If two sets have the same sum and xor are they necessarily the same?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let  $A = \{A_1, A_2, A_3, \cdots, A_n\}$  and $B = \{B_1, B_2, B_3,\cdots, B_n\}$.
where $A_i\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $B_i\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Say,

$$S_{1} = A_1 + A_2 + A_3 + \cdots + A_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n}{A_{i}} \\
     S_{2} = B_1 + B_2 + B_3 + \cdots + B_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n}{B_{i}}$$

And,

$$X_1 = A_1 \oplus A_2 \oplus A_3 \oplus \cdots \oplus A_n = \bigoplus_{i=1}^{n}{A_{i}} \\
    X_2 = B_1 \oplus B_2 \oplus B_3 \oplus \cdots \oplus B_n = \bigoplus_{i=1}^{n}{B_{i}}$$

Where [$\oplus$ is the XOR operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR).

If $S_{1} = S_{2}$ and $X_{1}=X_{2}$, does this imply that $A$ and $B$ contain the same set of integers?

Comment: Are you using $I$ to stand for the integers? and A1, etc., to stand for $A_1$, etc.?

Comment: @GerryMyerson   yes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Counterexample:
$$\begin{align*}
A &= \{ 1, 6, 8, 48 \} \\
B &= \{ 3, 4, 24, 32 \}
\end{align*}$$
More generally, any sets of integers of the form
$$
A = \{ 2^{a_k}, 2^{b_k} + 2^{c_k} \}_{k = 1,2,\ldots} \qquad\qquad B = \{ 2^{a_k} + 2^{b_k},  2^{c_k} \}_{k = 1,2,\ldots} $$
where the sequences $a_k, b_k, c_k$ never repeat and also don't have any elements in common, will be a counterexample. This can be generalised to any sequence of non-overlapping binary vectors, in which there are more vectors with [Hamming weight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight) 2 or greater than [Hamming weight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight) 1, interpreted as integers in binary notation.

Answer (score 6):

No. For example, $\{ 0, 3 \}$ and $\{1 , 2\}$ both have sum and xor $3$.